# How to get contract adress when contract is deployed uisng other contract?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, web3js

I have a smart contract with a function named, let's say, `deployNewContract(..)` this function takes some arguments and deployed a new contract based on the parameters. I am able to call the function from Ethereum-Wallet and deploy the contract. Everything works smooth.

Now, I have a public array of address type in which I store address of the newly deployed contract so I can get the address of the contract from that array.

Now the problem arises when I try to deploy the contract using `web3` or `geth` console. I execute the function of my contract and get the transaction hash and mine it obviously.

**But how do I get the address of newly deployed contract?**

Unfortunately, my pubic array shows no new entry this time and when I check `eth.getTransactionReciept`, I get `null` in contract address.

Here is output of `eth.getTRansactionReceipt(txHash);` :

```
{
  blockHash: "0xbde761102ec08bef4ba55a703261da071ba0e99b5ef6c8d7e77bf5c1a6e27ba1",
  blockNumber: 413,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 313570,
  from: "0x5cb1ffd42dea0afeefb8950adcb2b6e5cff2efc3",
  gasUsed: 313570,
  logs: [{
      address: "0x9d160c47ae9ccf33078c9513492e5499cee53439",
      blockHash: "0xbde761102ec08bef4ba55a703261da071ba0e99b5ef6c8d7e77bf5c1a6e27ba1",
      blockNumber: 413,
      data: "0x000000000000000000000000d573b1767915530a05a0250f5f4fc985427a6d534e65772050617469656e74205265676973746572656400000000000000000000",
      logIndex: 0,
      removed: false,
      topics: ["0xd5a6c4477254cab9dfc267110730e333e3c94ea3a93795b56c93b0c8757488ce"],
      transactionHash: "0x1b6e8970275eda4b39690cb868bd305983d483dee38a042a1bcfc3dbfada22d2",
      transactionIndex: 0
  }],
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  root: "0x87d205881fc430586b344d0dda84cf72ba99c6bd198171f6e42c008fcad7c993",
  to: "0x9d160c47ae9ccf33078c9513492e5499cee53439",
  transactionHash: "0x1b6e8970275eda4b39690cb868bd305983d483dee38a042a1bcfc3dbfada22d2",
  transactionIndex: 0
}
```

**PS:**

- I am on private test network
- I think it's more of what to do? So I am not posting my code (to avoid question from being lengthy). If you feel that code is needed, I will update the question.

Comment: Did you try triggering an event from that function to see if the contract is getting deployed by logging deployed contract's address?

Comment: How do you deploy a new contract? As Sanchit says you usually generate an event when you have to notify something.

Comment: I hadn't fired events. I should, my bad. Will post the results after adding events so that I can be sure that my contract gets deployed.